# League/Ranking table link

Tags: bug, profile-page

Why don't we have the link to the league table on the user profile page? Y'know, in the right corner, just above the histogram (like we have it on Stackoverflow)? Or is there another place on WP where there's a link to the league tables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice catch!

For those who don't follow, this is what the rep section of your profile looks on SO (and MSO):

> [image: SO Rep Panel]

<sup>Clicking on the link sends me [here](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31/1933347#1933347). Your results may vary.</sup>

And this is what it looks like here (and all non-SO sites I checked including Super User):

> [image: Our Rep Panel]

I have no idea why. This may be a good question to ask on MSO. It may even be a bug.

At any rate, if you want to check out your ranking in the league, you can visit [this page](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/195/week/workplace). That is for the weekly version, but you can see whatever you want with the handy dropdown.

Comment: Thanks jmac. I've [asked the same question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228170/league-ranking-link) on MSO like you recommended. I'm going to stay my hand for a bit and if no one shows up with an explanation, you'll get my acceptance.

Answer (score 4):

This was a bug. It somehow got turned off accidentally, but it should be working again now. Thanks for the report!

---

Turns out this was an expensive thing to calculate; we need to do some optimizing before turning it back on.

Comment: 'Should be working' - but if it isn't, what might be the reason? And I tried it with IE 9 and Chrome.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek Sorry, I commented on the MSO thread and forgot to update here as well. We had it turned back on, and then discovered it was very expensive to calculate for every single user on every single site. It's been turned off until we can figure out a way to optimize that.

Comment: How about a link there, instead of the ranking, so only if the link is clicked is the ranking calculated.  That would reduce the requests significantly.